# How to hook up Android Studio emulator from IDEA?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I was running into some issues with stage height in Android devices with notches, specifically the Xiaomi Note Pro 6. So since I don't have that device I wanted to emulate it using Android Studio.

How can I launch an app made in IDEA (Air app) that runs in the emulator?, so I can get the debug info from stage sizes and all the jazz, cant find a way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Help` | `Find Action` | `AVD Manager`, configure and start Android emulator from IntelliJ IDEA, then in the [Flash run/debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-flash-app.html) use the **Android device** option. It should see the running emulator (it has to be x86).

Comment: this needs to be printed on a huge paper and pinned to a wall